# Solution needed to compare different arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I compare an array of questions, for example, `var questions = ["q1", "q2"]`
to an answer array of boolean answers, for example, `var answers = ["false", "true"]`
The true false are radio buttons.

I have searched for solutions but haven't come across anything.

```
var questions = [
  "The Flag has 50 stripes.",
  "The Statue of Liberty is in NY City.",
  "Betsy Ross wrote the Star Spangled Banner.",
  "The Man from Uncle was really his cousin.",
  "Anne Margaret is the BOMB."
];

var answers = ["false", "true", "false", "false", "true"];
```

I expect when the false button is clicked for question one, an update to the wins count will increase by 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? If you are looking for corresponding elements, they would be elements with the same array index.

Comment: "same length, different contents" - what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to compare the questions index to the answer array's element at the same index. Below is some simple code that covers your quiz.

```js
let i = 0;
let winCount = 0;

var questions = [
  "The Flag has 50 stripes.",
  "The Statue of Liberty is in NY City.",
  "Betsy Ross wrote the Star Spangled Banner.",
  "The Man from Uncle was really his cousin.",
  "Anne Margaret is the BOMB."
];

var answers = ["false", "true", "false", "false", "true"];

function nextQ(answer) {
  if (answer) checkAnswer(answer);
  if (i >= questions.length) {
    return getResult();
  }
  document.getElementById('q').innerText = questions[i++];
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  if (answers[i - 1] === answer) winCount += 1;
}

function getResult() {
  const el = document.getElementById('res');
  el.innerText = `You have ${winCount} correct answers!`;
  el.style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.querySelectorAll('#q, button').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => nextQ(e.target.dataset.val))
})

nextQ();
```

```css
#q {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#q:after {
  content: '?';
}

#res {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #c0c0aa;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1cefff, #c0c0aa);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1cefff, #c0c0aa);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="q">

</div>
<button data-val="true">
  True
  </button>
<button data-val="false">
  False
</button>
<div id="res">

</div>
```

Note that `"false"` is a string, not a boolean.

Comment: This helped a lot. I do appreciate it.